# Migrating client app to FB 2.1

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-7

I use Delphi 7 with DBExpress.
I want to fully migrate my app to firebird 2.1. I already know what to do at the server side but not really sure at client side.

In the TSQLConnection component I see that vendorLib property points to GDS32.dll. The driverName is Interbase and getDriverFunc is getSQLDriverINTERBASE.

I don't know what to do in order to my connection use fbclient.dll. I tried simply changing gds32.dll to fbclient.dll in vendorLib, but it caused some access violations in my app.

Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Interbase DBX driver doesn't support Firebird 2.1 (you'll have problems with certain field types - BLOBs for example). There are rumors that D2010 (which must enter in [Beta](http://beta.embarcadero.com) soon) will support Firebird.

So, you can expect the Weawer or buy a commercial Firebird DBX driver (see Upscene's site or, DevArt/CoreLab's ones).

Also, perhaps is better that when you install Firebird to check the 'Generate gds32.dll for compatibility with older applications' - or something similar - I don't have now in front of my eyes the FB installation kit.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Use ZeosDB components for accessing FireBird DB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rename fbclient.dll to gds32.dll and replace it. Read [this](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq356/) - it's not exactly your case, but maybe you should try the same way.

Answer (score 0):

There is also some dbx drivers for Firebird in UIB in \Misc\dbexpress

For completing this I know also dbx drivers for Delphi 2007/2009 at IBExpert

http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Main.News#news16

and others connectivity to access Firebird with Delphi
http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq7/